# FQL returning empty response when querying privacy table, probably permissions error

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I am doing this query:

```
SELECT value FROM privacy WHERE id=10203382033336176
```

Unfortunately Facebook is giving me an empty array as a response. Which permission setting should I request so I can see a current logged user's privacy setting on a specific post?

Edit:
Ok, I tried the FQL Tool on Facebook's developers page and I got this reponse using the same query, same access token:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

There may be a problem if the post has it's privacy setting set as "Only me"? The FQL shouldn't at least return that ? :D

Scopes requested from the Access Token Debugger:

```
    basic_info, export_stream, public_profile, read_stream, user_friends
```

Comment: have you worked with, or are you working with, Facebook's Graph Explorer tool?

Comment: go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ click on FQL query.

Comment: Sorry, edited and included FB Graph Explorer FQL's response.

Comment: what ID is that? because there is no field called simply id that I can see.. app_id. object_id?

Comment: it will return an error if you don't have authentication.. so that's not the issue per-say.. you probably will need to request/set an access token at some point though.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy/ - "id is an alias for object_id" . The id in question is returned from FB.ui call with "feed" as method. The id is the response.post_id returned in the callback.

Comment: Ok, I got something. I tried this with another post from my timeline which was marked as "Public" the whole time. Seems like if the post is marked as "Only me", Facebook doesn't return a thing. I will work around this if there is no other explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like privacy table in FQL is a little bugged. I ended up using GraphAPI, requesting the /"UID_PID" response.privacy['value'] .